# dmDeviceName is just 'c'

Tags: c++, winapi, dev-mode

I'm trying to get the names of each of my monitors using [`DEVMODE.dmDeviceName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183565%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> **dmDeviceName**
>   A zero-terminated character array that specifies the "friendly" name of the printer or display; for example, "PCL/HP LaserJet" in the case of PCL/HP LaserJet. This string is unique among device drivers. Note that this name may be truncated to fit in the dmDeviceName array.

I'm using the following code:

```
log.printf("Device Name: %s",currDevMode.dmDeviceName);
```

But for every monitor, the name is printed as just `c`. All other information from DEVMODE seems to print ok. What's going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely you are using the Unicode version of the structure and thus are passing wide characters to `printf`. Since you use a format string that implies `char` data there is a mis-match.

The UTF-16 encoding results in every other byte being 0 for characters in the ASCII range and so `printf` thinks that the second byte of the first two byte character is actually a null-terminator.

This is the sort of problem that you get with `printf` which of course has no type-safety. Since you are using C++ it's probably worth switching to `iostream` based I/O.

However, if you want to use ANSI text, as you indicate in a comment, then the simplest solution is to use the ANSI `DEVMODEA` version of the struct and the corresponding `A` versions of the API functions, e.g. `EnumDisplaySettingsA`, `DeviceCapabilitiesA`.

Comment: Hmm, when using EnumDisplaySettingsA I get `cannot convert parameter 1 from 'WCHAR *' to 'LPCSTR'`, where parameter 1 is monitorInfo.szDevice, retrieved using `GetMonitorInfo`.

Comment: It's all or nothing. You need `GetMonitorInfoA` as well as `EnumDisplaySettingsA`. Of course, you could just switch your project config to ANSI. For background read this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd374089(VS.85).aspx

Comment: The API to convert wide to ANSI is [`WideCharToMultiByte()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd374130(VS.85).aspx). It's not the simplest to use so if you can call the ANSI APIs instead then you'll find thing easier.

Comment: Using your suggestion of switching to `A` suffixed methods, I've now got `printf("%s",currMode.dmDeviceName)` outputting `cdd`!

Comment: I'm hoping that `cdd` is what you are looking for!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4322/discussion-between-fredley-and-david-heffernan)

Comment: I've just call `EnumDisplaySettings` and I also see a device name of cdd. Don't ask me what that means, but I'm pretty confident that you are getting the right value from the system.

Comment: The damn "cdd", very strange combination of characters (maybe an acronym?) that lead us to confusion and to investigate why, because it seems a bad output string since the documentation says it should return a "Friendly name" (like "PCL/HP LaserJet"), but "cdd" is not friendly in any way. However, if we all are getting the same "cdd" then I think that is the right return value.

Comment: I suspect the "cdd" stands for "Canonical Display Driver" (there's a system file in Windows called cdd.dll that is the canonical display driver). If anyone knows otherwise, please correct me.

Answer (score 2):

`dmDeviceName` is `TCHAR[]` so if you're compiling for unicode, the first wide character will be interpreted as a 'c' followed by a zero terminator.

You will need to convert it to ascii or use unicode capable printing routines.

Comment: How would I convert it to ascii? I can't change the way `log` works.

Comment: @fredley I've covered that in the final paragraphs of my answer.